# serialization exception in sending complex object in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have testing the sending an object with dataContractSerialization to a client program with WCF.

At client program, at line of convert stream to my object (second line in below):

```
DataContractSerializer mySerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Employee));
Employee emp =(Employee) mySerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
```

this error occurs:

> Error in line 1 position 131.
>   Expecting element 'Employee' from
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComplexObjectClient'..
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name
>   'Employee', namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComplexObjectServe

what?

Comment: How are you creating your service reference? Does your client have a reference to the assembly containing the "ComplexObjectServe" types?

Comment: with right click on the project in solution explorer and Add service Reference... . i have a class called Employee and this class exist in server and client projects. yes, i doing this work with xmlSerialixer class and it working properly but with dataContractSerialixer not work!!!?

Comment: There is no need for you to manually serialize your objects - WCF takes care of this for you.

Comment: thanks Greg Sansom; yes, it is work properly. so what is dataContractSerializer? whether WCF use from dataContractSerializer as internally for serializing? and what is usage dataContractSerializer?